# Authentication on facebook in c++

Tags: c++, facebook, authentication, oauth

I've searched on the internet for days now but I can't seem to find any decent example. My understanding of the oauth2 flow is (please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. client program asks facebook for a request_token
2. client program starts a browser, giving it an address containing the client_id and the request_token, and yields to the browser
3. user logs in/subscribes and accepts the request_token
4. as soon as focus is returned to the client program, the program sends the request_token it got previously to check it's been authorized; if so, an access token is returned
5. as long as the access_token is valid, the client program is free to access whatever it needed to

This seems to be confirmed by the oauth2 stub and [this page](http://cms.getsatisfaction.com/developers/authentication), but I can't find any way to get a request_token in facebook. Even [here](http://www.reijo.org/scribbles/list-of-oauth-service-providers) I couldn't find anything useful. Also getting an access_token or a signed_request containing an access_token would be fine.

The platforms my program should run on include MacOSX, iOS, Win32, Linux. We can currently do http/https communication, and platform-specific code such as ShellExecute() on Win32 is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check out the [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) instead of looking at the documentation of a provider that implements OAuth 1.0?

As Facebook doesn't implement a flow that directly suits your requirements, the next best flow for you to use would be the [Client Side Authentication flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/).

It basically works like this:

1. Open some web browser/view from your application and direct it to Facebook's `/dialog/oauth` endpoint with the parameters as query string.
2. Let the user log in and grant your application access rights inside it.
3. Catch the `access_token` fragment from the response redirection in the browser view.

How you open a web browser/view from your application and how you catch the redirect highly depens on the operating system/libraries you're using, but should be doable with a little research.

Comment: Because there is nothing relevant in there. We don't use Javascript and we don't receive cookies nor manage sessions in our game. Also, we don't want to embed a browser inside our game. I don't think I'm being unreasonable here. As of getting something out of a browser, I think it's very very unreliable. There are so many browsers out there I don't even heard about half of them (mobile, custom GUI, command line...)

Comment: The Client Side Authentication flow is not bound to using Javascript. It should be used for every application where you have the relevant OAuth parts running on the user's machine. All OAuth flows, that are implemented by Facebook and involve a user, require the user to log in to Facebook inside a browser. If you can't orchestrate a browser or embed a web browser/view, there's currently no way to achieve what you want, until Facebook releases the cumbersome [Devices flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/).